# Gaps between primes: bounds - a question of possibilty

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-verification

Let $n$ be any given natural number. Let $p$ be the very next prime greater than $n$. Let $b$ be the bound for the prime gap above $n$. Here, the bound is strictly the limit from $n$ to $p$, meaning that $n$+$b$ is greater than or equal to $p$. $n$+$b$ will never be less than $p$. Most often, $n$+$b$ will be greater than p. Sometimes, $n$+$b$ will be equal to p.

I was told that Legendre's conjecture implies that the prime gap above any natural number $n$ is bounded by the product of a constant and the $\sqrt n$. Now, I need to reconsider this. I have discovered a new function for what Legendre's conjecture implies.

Actually, I have strong reason to think that this factor by which the constant is multiplied is not $\sqrt n$.

The question is this: Is it possible for this factor to be a whole number that is less than $\sqrt n$? Is this a possibility which would be consistent with all the leading theories?

Is the following possible?:

The factor could be less than the square root of $n$. The bound is 2 multiplied by a factor. 2 is the constant. The factor is not the square root of $n$. It is a whole number that is less than the square root of $n$.

I believe this.

Comment: I find it extremely difficult to comprehend what the question is.

Comment: Same here.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I typed it fast.

Comment: Some context is suggested by [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951190/will-this-limit-apply-both-to-primes-and-to-composites), as also with a number of the OP's recent posts.  However this "Question" needs to have a specific question posed to anchor it.

Comment: The question as to whether this is a possibility or not actually was in the subject line originally, but it was edited. I think I know what the factor in question actually is, but I want verification.

Comment: Particularly with the recent edits, it almost seems that you are conjecturing a constant bound on prime gaps, but of course that is well known to be impossible.  Rather than beat around the bush, you should state clearly what it is you think is "possible" about bounds on prime gaps.  Only then can a willing Reader give you a clear written response.

Comment: "From n to the next p can be no farther than n+n-2", so the bound is n-2, right? Now, it is possible for the bound to be equal to the product of a constant, which I think is 2, and $\sqrt n$. This would not be an impossible constant bound, right?

Comment: The bound, I believe, is the product of two factors. One factor is constant and I believe it to be 2. The other factor is what my question is about and let it be represented by a symbol, maybe f for factor. Suppose the way to calculate f is to take the square root of n and subtract something which is not a constant from it. So then the bound 2f would not be a constant bound, right?

Comment: What Legendre's conjecture implies is mysterious. There is a deep mystery. Studying Legendre's conjecture has led me to a series of surprises. Now, I have found a new, most interesting function, which I have named for Legendre. In the years to come, I hope to share my findings from this present year. There is more to this often overlooked conjecture which was made over two centuries ago than most realize. Well, there is a new function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have strong reasons for thinking the prime gap should not be so large, namely [Cramér's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture), which is a heuristic argument that the prime gap should be $O((\log n)^2)$.

But so far the best we can do is show the gap is $O(\sqrt{n} \log n)$, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis (this is also due to Cramér).

Comment: I can now see why those two conjectures are what they are. Shall we investigate those two conjectures? I have a plan for Riemann's conjecture and a powerful tool to work with.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung If you have a powerful approach to the Riemann Hypothesis, why not keep the million dollar prize for yourself? :)

Comment: I would advise you, Jeffrey, to take a good introductory Number Theory text, say, Niven-Zuckerman-Montgomery, and do all the exercises. If you have any trouble with that, there's no point whatsoever in thinking about the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @Slade Logistics. I do not have the means to put text into pdf. I am very limited, working mostly on paper with pencil, using a calculator. Take into account the two year wait. I am looking at the next few years. I know for sure that Legendre's conjecture is true.

Comment: Everybody knows Legendre's conjecture is true, Jeffrey. Everyone knows the twin prime conjecture is true, and everyone knows the Goldbach conjecture is true. Unfortunately, knowing something is true has proven to be of no use in finding a proof that it's true.